# ASP.NET MVC View not rendering script tags properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have a very simple MVC project, and in my _Layout.cshtml I have some js includes like so:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

However, when it renders, it renders on the page like (note the tilde on the first one):

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I can't seem to get it to render properly, and it doesn't matter which script tag is first, that's the one it adds/keeps the tilde on.  I've resorted to including the jquery script twice, the first one will have a tilde but the second one will get included, but I don't like that solution at all.

I'm working with VS 2012, it's a .NET 4.5 MVC application.  From my searches it seems this was a known issue for Razor v1, but the solutions they provide don't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`@Url.Content()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper (We're not in ASP.NET any more, toto).

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Another option is to use the [`Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/) package and create bundles:

**BundleConfig.cs

```
public void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  // ...
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/site").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/easing.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
  ));
  // ...
}
```

Then in your page use:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js/site")
```

Comment: As an update, MVC and razor support this now out of the box (for scripts and stylesheets). There is no need for `Url.Content` (unless you _want_ to do so for your own sake).

Answer (score 1):

Either stick the references in a bundle and use `@Scripts.Render("~/bundlename")` or use

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>
```