# Submit button message not fired with script when action click is submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I want to have a script to validate if a field called Email is not empty.  I created a script which I put in the SCRIPTS folder.  But nothing is fired when we click the Create button.  Any idea of what is wrong with this ?  Thanks

ValidationEmail.js

```
     $(function () {
        $("SubmitBTNCreate").click, function (e) {
           var email = $("#Email").val();
           if (email == "")  {
               e.preventDefault();
               alert("Please enter an email address.");
           }
        });
     });
```

Create.cshmtl

```
 @model codefirst.Models.Personne

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }



 <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <fieldset>
    <legend>Personne</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nom)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nom)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nom)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prenom)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prenom)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prenom)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)   <== field to check if empty
    </div>

    <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Create" id="SubmitBTNCreate" />  <== btn submit
     </p>
 </fieldset>
 }

 <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>

 @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ValidationEmail")   <== calling the script
```

}

Comment: What version your jquery is? Open console and write `$.fn.jquery` to see. Other than that, see the generated html and check if the input has REALLY id `Email`, because I remember working on a project which added some names to the id so the `$('#Email')` would not work.

Comment: Also you are expecting something wrong. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)   <== field to check if empty` if I remember right, `ValidationMessageFor` is not an input, it's a div with errors (if any). If you really want to test the div, change the .`val()` from the answers to `var email = $("#Email").empty()` or `var email = $("#Email").html() === ''` to return true or false

Comment: Jquery version is 1.8.2  I found a error 404 Not found  url: http://localhost:50821/Scripts/ValidationEmail     in the Scripts folder I got ValidationEmail.js

Comment: tried `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ValidationEmail.js")` instead? I don't have VS at work so can't test that atm. Anyways, now you know that your code does not work because you are not loading the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem with your help.

in the Create.cshtml  I added the .js to the script name

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ValidationEmail.js")
```

In the script I was missing the "#" in front of #SubmitBTNCreate

Validation.js

```
  $(function () {
     $("#SubmitBTNCreate").on("click", function (e) {
       var email = $("#Email").val();
       if (email == "") {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Please enter an email address.");
       }
     });
  });
```

or this also work

```
      $(function () {
     $("#SubmitBTNCreate").click ( function (e) {
       var email = $("#Email").val();
       if (email == "") {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Please enter an email address.");
       }
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax errors, missing # and click binding is wrong:

```
$("SubmitBTNCreate").click, function (e) {
```

I would rewrite it as this:

```
$(function () {
   $("#SubmitBTNCreate").click(function(e) {
      // use preventDefault() at top
      e.preventDefault();
      var email = $("#Email").val();
      // asking with shorter format works and looks better
      if (!email)  {
         alert("Please enter an email address.");
         return false;
      }
      // no errors, submit form by id you give it
      $("#yourFormId").submit();
   });
});
```

Edit:

Problem with include might get solved by including it this way:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ValidationEmail.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting, this fixes javascript bugs though. I assume that jQuery is correctly loaded if you view network tab and no errors at javascript console? if there is, would like to see them updated to question.

Comment: V  I check the Network (I am using Chrome Pf12).  I can't see the script been called ValidationEmail.  Should I see it there ?  I see jquery-1.8.2.js. browserLink, negociate?requestURL, etc

Comment: On page load you should see at least jquery and your ValidationEmail.js (or whatever it names is) - if you dont see the latter, there is no way that validation nor click could work. :)

Comment: I got a page 404 not found url http://localhost:50821/Scripts/ValidationEmail  but the scripts is under the project folder Scripts with the name of ValidationEmail.js

Comment: so the problem is that it is not a bundle and you are including it as bundle format? :) progress! does this help for include? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012190/asp-net-mvc-view-not-rendering-script-tags-properly

Answer (score 0):

Use this, You are missing `#` in ID selector and you are missing binding the event

```
 $(function () {
        $("#SubmitBTNCreate").bind('click', function (e) {
           var email = $("#Email").val();
           if (email == "")  {
               e.preventDefault();
               alert("Please enter an email address.");
           }
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give your form an ID in the `@using (Html.BeginForm())` as in order to do any validation, you need to prevent the form from submitting on the button click. So what'd you'd want is something along the lines of `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "emailForm" }))`. This will allow you to reference it from your javascript.

With that in place, you'll be able to fix your bugs in your javascript function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // You're missing the # to tell jQuery you're looking by ID
    // You also had a ',' instead of a '('
    $("#SubmitBTNCreate").click( function (e) {
        // The very first thing you need to do is prevent the default 
        // because it will fire off asynchronously.
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        // Also allow for IE8
        else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }

        var email = $("#Email").val();
        if (email == "")  {
            alert("Please enter an email address.");
        }
        else {
            // If you have no validation errors, submit the form.
            $("#emailForm").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the screen is not returning anything when I click Create    the url is /Home/Create/emailform

Comment: Try filling out the other parameters in the `BeginForm` method. The overload I typically use is `BeginForm(*action*, *controller*, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "emailForm"})`. So you would replace *action* with "Create", and *controller* with "Home". That should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following line needs fixing:

```
$("#SubmitBTNCreate").on("click", function (e) {
// ^id selector       ^ use on() to bind event listener
```

Full code

```
   $(function () {
        $("#SubmitBTNCreate").on("click", function (e) {
           var email = $("#Email").val();
           if (email == "")  {
               e.preventDefault();
               alert("Please enter an email address.");
           }
        });
     });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6S8E/)

Comment: not working also.... It should be so easy this... I tried your demo and I agree it is working.  But I guess with Razor something is different